# Database design for relationships

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have 3 tables
Table1:  Plant Table

PlantId(Primary key)

Plantname

and some other fields

Table2 :Inputfiles

Plantname,Filename

PlantId(foreign key) references PlantId(Plant)

Table 3; InputData

Id.

and other fields

I need to design it such a way that one plant can have many inpufiles So this is a 1-m between Plant Table and Inputfiles tables

Now when the user selects a inputfile from table2, all the data related to the input file is stored in Inputdata table3.

What should be the relation between table2(input files) and table3(inputdata)

Thank you

sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1-1 relationship should exist between inputfiles and inputdata.

Based on your description of the problem, I would have inputfiles have the inputdata.id as a foreign key.